# What version of chrome is required for selenium version 3.7.1 or alternatively 3.5.3

Tags: java, maven, google-chrome, selenium

I'm getting the "Only local connections are allowed" issue reported [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5022) on ubuntu 17.04 with the following set of java selenium, chrome and chrome driver.

```
Selenium - version 3.7.1
Chrome Driver 2.33.506092
Chromium Version 62.0.3202.89 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 17.04 (64-bit)
```

As well with chrome-stable Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I'm wondering what is the latest recommended set of stable software versions 3.7.1 and 3.5.3.. e.i what version of chrome and driver goes with each?

I'm using the following maven dependencies with either 3.5.3 or 3.7.1. I'm thinking an update to chrome caused both to stop working for me however I'm not certain other than I had been using both 3.5.3 effectively and then 3.7.1 effectively until yesterday when I began getting this error. I believe I updated my system yesterday as well.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I recalled I had backed up my virtual machine recently.

I do have a working version with

```
ChromeDriver 2.33.506092
Chromium Version 62.0.3202.89 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu
running on Ubuntu 17.04 (64-bit)

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

which also works with 3.5.3 and 3.7.1

and after updating the system with a chromium update works fine,

Ah a git pull and the system breaks.. must be something in the code.

And actually from what I can tell the message ""Only local connections are allowed"" is not a problem as it appears even when the system is working. I was confused by so many other posts on that being an error. It's probably not an error but rather the last message shown to the user before the system crashes.

**UPDATE 2:** 
I seem to be having this same issue described here. The described random nature may have caused some confusion.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/8yZDv_h8feg
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4961

```
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.10.0-40-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.09 seconds
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:01:39.354Z'
System info: host: 'ubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.10.0-40-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.10.0-40-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.09 seconds
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:01:39.354Z'
System info: host: 'ubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.10.0-40-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
```

Regards
Conteh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recalled I had backed up my virtual machine recently.

I do have a working version with

```
ChromeDriver 2.33.506092
Chromium Version 62.0.3202.89 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu
running on Ubuntu 17.04 (64-bit)

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

which also works with 3.5.3 and 3.7.1

**UPDATE:** After working fine for some days of development, again I seem to be having this same error described here. The described random nature may have caused my confusion.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/8yZDv_h8feg

The problem must be the update to chromium-browser that ends up causing this problem.

There has been an updates since the working version. Perhaps .94 doesn't play well with chrome-driver.

62.0.3202.89-0ubuntu0.17.04.1386
62.0.3202.94-0ubuntu0.17.04.1388

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/zesty/+source/chromium-browser

As well if I revert to my working virtual machine backup and update only the code to be the same as on the broken system, the code works launching chromium.

So I guess the answer for now is to not update to the latest version of chromium.

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on the version of chromedriver you are running, here is a link that tells you the supported versions of chrome browser/driver

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.26/notes.txt

You can also check the current chrome driver release here:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

I can see that you are running:

Chrome Driver 2.33.506092

You cans see in the documentation:

----------ChromeDriver v2.23 (2016-08-04)----------
Supports Chrome v51-53

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's somewhat helpful.. I'm aware that ChromeDriver v2.33 (2017-10-03) Supports Chrome v60-62. That's my setup. However it's not working as expected.